# EventTrigger not working inside ItemsControl in MVVM

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, mvvm

I want to bind multiple buttons dynamically in MVVM.
1.I Dynamically created buttons using ItemControl 
2. It did not Invoke Trigger Click Event. 
Please help me on this.

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ComponentList,Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Button Tag="{Binding WorkFlowCompId}">
                                <Button.Content>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ComponentName,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                </Button.Content>
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ComponentSelected}" 
CommandParameter="{Binding WorkFlowCompId,Mode=TwoWay}" >
                                        </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: What is this i:Interaction.Triggers?

Comment: xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" I am using Microsoft.Expression.Interactions for intractions

Comment: Then you probably need to specify it in your question.

Comment: The code is right at first look. Try to check that command is bound to InvokeCommandAction and remove TwoWay binding mode from ItemsSource

Comment: Is ComponentSelected on the item or the parent?

Comment: Why are you using a EventTrigger instead of the Button's own `Command` property?

Comment: Several solutions have been presented here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085846/mvvm-light-commands-within-an-itemscontrol?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that the command is getting the context from its template and there it cannot access the root of the ViewModel. Add this class to your solution:

```
public class DataContextProxy : FrameworkElement
    {
        public DataContextProxy()
        {
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(DataContextProxyLoaded);
        }

        void DataContextProxyLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Binding binding = new Binding();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(BindingPropertyName))
            {
                binding.Path = new PropertyPath(BindingPropertyName);
            }
            binding.Source = this.DataContext;
            binding.Mode = BindingMode;
            this.SetBinding(DataContextProxy.DataSourceProperty, binding);
        }

        public Object DataSource
        {
            get { return (Object)GetValue(DataSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DataSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DataSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DataSource", typeof(Object), typeof(DataContextProxy), null);


        public string BindingPropertyName { get; set; }

        public BindingMode BindingMode { get; set; }

    }
```

then use it in you XAML like so:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
            <library:DataContextProxy x:Key="DataContextProxy"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

Then in your command binding:

```
<Button Tag="{Binding WorkFlowCompId}">
                                <Button.Content>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ComponentName,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                </Button.Content>
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataSource.ComponentSelected, Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}" 
CommandParameter="{Binding WorkFlowCompId,Mode=TwoWay}" >
                                        </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

A first pass at what you Xaml should look like:-

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ComponentList}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Command="{Binding SelectComponent}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ComponentName}"/>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

I suspect as Derek alludes to in his comment you have a `ComponentSelected` command on the container.  However you should move this command ot the view model for the component.  Note I've also renamed it to `SelectComponent` so that is sounds like an action rather than a property.

TwoWay binding has been removed it wouldn't be doing anything in this case.  Assigning a Tag value from a simple binding should be setting off alarm bells that the design is having some problems.

BTW, since you are doing a form of selection would not a `ListBox` be more appropriate in this case?