# Bind items from two different ObservableCollection to one control

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a parent DataGrid and inside that DataGrid I have a inner DataGrid.My objective is to populate the inner datagrid on row click of my parent DataGrid.Below is my code:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding GuestHostTotalList}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="16,15,-14,-15" x:Name="dataGridParent" 
                      Style="{StaticResource EfesDataGridStyle}" FrozenColumnCount="14" GridLinesVisibility="All" 
                      HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#DADADA" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#DADADA" Cursor="Hand" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                      RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible"  >
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                        <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="UpdateEvent" TargetObject="{Binding}"></ei:CallMethodAction>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="28"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Border x:Name="BackgroundBorder" BorderThickness="0" Background="{StaticResource Siyah}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource Siyah}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                                        <ContentPresenter Margin="6,3,6,3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                        <Path x:Name="SortArrow" Visibility="Collapsed" Data="M0,0 L1,0 0.5,1 z" Stretch="Fill" Grid.Column="3" Width="8" Height="6" Fill="White" Margin="0,0,8,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.4" />
                                        <Rectangle Width="1" Fill="#AAC377" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                                        <Rectangle Width="1" Margin="0,0,1,0" Fill="#425B10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                                        <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" Visibility="Hidden" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                        <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" Visibility="Hidden" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                                    </Grid>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="{x:Null}">
                                            <Setter TargetName="BackgroundBorder" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Siyah}" />
                                            <Setter TargetName="BackgroundBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <MultiTrigger>
                                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                                                <Condition Property="SortDirection" Value="{x:Null}" />
                                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="BackgroundBorder" Value="{StaticResource ASiyah}" />
                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="BackgroundBorder" Value="{StaticResource ASiyah}" />
                                        </MultiTrigger>
                                        <MultiTrigger>
                                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true" />
                                                <Condition Property="SortDirection" Value="{x:Null}" />
                                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <Setter TargetName="BackgroundBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ASiyah}" />
                                            <Setter TargetName="BackgroundBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ASiyah}" />
                                        </MultiTrigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="Ascending">
                                            <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                            <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="RenderTransform">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="180" />
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="Descending">
                                            <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="DisplayIndex" Value="0">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="PART_LeftHeaderGripper"></Setter>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <DataGrid.Columns>                    
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kod" Binding="{Binding Code}"  Width="50*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tarih" Binding="{Binding History}" Width="70*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ev Sahibi" Binding="{Binding Own}" Width="100*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Konuk" Binding="{Binding Guest}" Width="50*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="1" Binding="{Binding One_guest}" Width="30*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="X" Binding="{Binding X_game}" Width="30*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="2" Binding="{Binding Two_guest}" Width="30*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="T1" Binding="{Binding T1_host}" Width="30*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="TX" Binding="{Binding TX_host}" Width="30*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="T2" Binding="{Binding T2_host}" Width="30*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="+"  CellStyle ="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}"  Binding="{Binding TotalOptions}" Width="30*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Min" Binding="{Binding MinOption}" Width="30*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Lig" Binding="{Binding League}" Width="70*" />
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Durum" Width="Auto" >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ToggleButton  x:Name="toggleBtn" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource SlidingToggleButton}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" IsChecked="{Binding ToggleBtn}" Background="#FF2F63FF" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>                    
                </DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                        <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="RowClick"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
                </DataGrid.Resources>            

                <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate x:Uid="test123">
                    <DataTemplate x:Name="testTemplete">
                        <DataGrid x:Name="innerGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding SubGridItemList}" Style="{StaticResource EfesDataGridStyle}" Margin="50,2,2,2" MinHeight="40"  GridLinesVisibility="All" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#DADADA" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#DADADA" Visibility="Collapsed" >
                            <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"></Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="28"></Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"></Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <Border x:Name="BackgroundBorder" BorderThickness="0" Background="{StaticResource Siyah}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource Siyah}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                                                    <ContentPresenter Margin="6,3,6,3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                    <Path x:Name="SortArrow" Visibility="Collapsed" Data="M0,0 L1,0 0.5,1 z" Stretch="Fill" Grid.Column="3" Width="8" Height="6" Fill="White" Margin="0,0,8,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.4" />
                                                    <Rectangle Width="1" Fill="#AAC377" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                                                    <Rectangle Width="1" Margin="0,0,1,0" Fill="#425B10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                                                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" Visibility="Hidden" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" Visibility="Hidden" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                                                </Grid>
                                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                    <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="{x:Null}">
                                                        <Setter TargetName="BackgroundBorder" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Siyah}" />
                                                        <Setter TargetName="BackgroundBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                    <MultiTrigger>
                                                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                                                            <Condition Property="SortDirection" Value="{x:Null}" />
                                                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="BackgroundBorder" Value="{StaticResource ASiyah}" />
                                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="BackgroundBorder" Value="{StaticResource ASiyah}" />
                                                    </MultiTrigger>
                                                    <MultiTrigger>
                                                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true" />
                                                            <Condition Property="SortDirection" Value="{x:Null}" />
                                                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                                        <Setter TargetName="BackgroundBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ASiyah}" />
                                                        <Setter TargetName="BackgroundBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ASiyah}" />
                                                    </MultiTrigger>
                                                    <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="Ascending">
                                                        <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                                        <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="RenderTransform">
                                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                                <RotateTransform Angle="180" />
                                                            </Setter.Value>
                                                        </Setter>
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                    <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="Descending">
                                                        <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                    <Trigger Property="DisplayIndex" Value="0">
                                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="PART_LeftHeaderGripper"></Setter>
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                                    <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="InnerGridRowClick"/>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kod" Binding="{Binding Kod}" Width="400" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Alt Secenakler" Binding="{Binding Alt_Secenakler}" Width="500" />                                
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGrid.Resources>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
                            </DataGrid.Resources>
                        </DataGrid>                      
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            </DataGrid>
```

In the above code you can see dataGridParent is parent datagrid and innerGrid is the inner DataGrid.Now I have two observable collections in my viewmodel 1.GuestHostTotalList(is the itemsource of my parent DataGrid) and 2.SubGridItemList (this is used as ItemSource of my innerDataGrid).But I am seeing the inner grid is not populating with the data.
Can anyone help me.Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the 'inner' `DataGrid` inside the `DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate`. This `Template` is used to display the row details. Therefore, your `SubGridItemList` collection should be in the data object that is displayed in each row of the 'outer' `DataGrid`.

So, you have a collection called `GuestHostTotalList` which is bound to the outer `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property. Whatever the type of data is in this collection is the type of data that need to add a collection property to bind to the inner `DataGrid.ItemSource` if you want your binding to work.

Comment: so as per you there is no way I can bind two different observable collections which are not related to my innerDataGrid.thanks for reply.

Comment: That is not what I said. You have not been clear about what you actually want to achieve... you said you had an error, so I explained why you were getting an error.

Comment: ok..Then @Sheridan may I know in the present context what is best possible way to solve this or what is the best approach to do this.My objective is onclick of a row some data has to be populated in my inner grid.Now these data may be related to row data or may not be.So I created this separate observableCollection.Now I would like to know what is best approach to achieve this.Can you please suggest. Thanking you.

Comment: And what condition should decide which collection should be used at any particular time?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly bind the inner DataGrid to the collection "SubGridItemList" because right right now its DataContext is that of the "GuestHostTotalList". What you have to do is to be able to jump from "GuestHostTotalList" to the ViewModel DataContext.

Please find my solution to a similar problem here:
[EventTrigger not working inside ItemsControl in MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576487/eventtrigger-not-working-inside-itemscontrol-in-mvvm/5623595#5623595)

By using the DataContextProxy class you can jump from within the "GuestHostTotalList" context to the ViewModel context and will be able to bind "SubGridItemList": {Binding DataSource.SubGridItemList, Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}